# What to expect from a Reverse Engineering technical test with IDA for a junior position? Experiences?

Tags: ida

I'm excited about the prospect of taking a technical Reverse Engineering test for a junior position that I've been trying to secure. The test is expected to last around 3 hours, and I've been informed that I'll need to use IDA. I'm curious to know what I can expect from this type of test and if any of you have ever had a similar experience.

I would love to hear your experiences and receive advice regarding what might be included in the test. What kind of challenges could arise during the process? Are there any specific aspects of IDA that I should focus on more? And, in general, how can I best prepare to successfully tackle this test?

Any advice, accounts of past experiences, or useful resources would be greatly appreciated. I'm genuinely motivated to learn and grow in this field, and I'm thankful for any help you can provide.